# Encoding and Decoding excel file as Base64 string

Tags: c#, closedxml

This is for a `Windows Console App`

I am saving an `Excel` file that I am using as a template for reports as a `Base64` `string`. using the code below to encode the file as a `base64` `string`. I then store it in an `SQL` Database as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

```
Stream myStream = null;
string base64String;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
using (myStream)
{
    myStream.CopyTo(ms);
    byte[] excelBytes = ms.ToArray();
    base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(excelBytes, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
    FileNameTxt.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
}
```

I then retrieve this file and decode the string and create a `ClosedXML` excel file.

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        StoredFile = reader["StoredFile"].ToString();

    }
    reader.Close();

    wb = workBook(StoredFile);
}

public static XLWorkbook workBook(string File)
{
    byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(File);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);

    XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook(ms);
    return wb;
}
```

The problem is that the end result is a workbook that has lost some of its formatting. mainly appears to have only affected border formatting.

I don't know if it is an issue with the encoding, decoding or generation of new file using `ClosedXML` that is causing the issue. Any direction or thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you'd have problem with BAse64/reading from DB creation of the document would fail completely - it is really unlikely to have problems with binary<->base64 conversion and at the same time endup with valid ZIP. Look somewhere else.

Comment: If you think it's the encoding or decoding, why not make a quick app to choose a file, encode it, decode the encoding, and save, so you can compare the input and output?

Comment: So I would think it is (and not counting it out) something to do the encoding and decoding simply because once I encode it I can use that same string over and over again and the format is identical every time. if I encode the same file again and decode it the resulting file has a new formatting issue. Which If I decode that string over and over each time I end up with the same formatting issue. So it does not appear to be an issue with the ClosedXML, if it were you would think it would be a new issue every time with the same string

Comment: Your myStream is null, how can you be using it for anything?

Comment: Nice catch, I actually bundled up some of the important details close to each other so I could give everyone an idea of how the code works, I should have left that part out so it didn't confuse anyone but trust me the working code doesn't have a null myStream

Comment: So far I have switched from ClosedXML to OpenXML SDK 2.5 and I have been able to generate one report with no issues. 
I don't want to say yet that was the cause of it until I get my second report through it with no issues