# VBA Byte array written to xlsx file does not open

Tags: vba, decode, xlsx

I have code that receives a Base64 string and decodes it into a byte array. The byte array is then written to file, this seems to work fine for pdf documents but an xlsx Excel file does not seem to open? What do I need to adjust to write xlsx files as well, does it need to decode the string in a different way or does the writing to file need adjustment?

Decode code -

```
Private Function DecodeBase64(ByVal strData As String) As Byte()

    Dim objXML As Object
    Dim objNode As Object

    
    Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    
    Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")
    objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
    objNode.text = strData
    DecodeBase64 = objNode.nodeTypedValue

   
    Set objNode = Nothing
    Set objXML = Nothing

End Function
```

Write code -

```
strPath = "C:\Users\" & User(1) & "\Downloads\Temp\" & ConsignmentNumber & " " & EntryFound & " " & Counter & " " & "." & FileType

byteArr = DecodeBase64(sString)

Open strPath For Binary Access Write As #1
lWritePos = 1
Put #1, lWritePos, byteArr
Close #1
```

```
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
```

The above is what is output from the API as a base64 string, I have used an online converter for it and it outputs a readable xlsx file just fine but the same base 64 string decoded and then written to file is unable to be read? Is there a different way to decode an xlsx file perhaps? Or is changing it to a binary array and writing it as a Binary file causing the issue?

Comment: @FaneDuru so if I get an xlsx file from my API as a base64 string.. how am I supposed to retrieve it/decode it so I can open it as an xlsx file? Is it really not possible to send and receive Excel worksheets via API?

Comment: @FaneDuru It doesn't matter at all what kind of file is send. As long as encoding and decoding is correct, the content should be an exact copy of the original file.

Comment: @Drawleeh: Where does the encoded content comes from? Are you sure you deal with an xlsx file? If you have you access to the source file: Is the content of the file you wrote identical to the source file?

Comment: @FunThomas I was wrong (and superficial), indeed. I will delete my answer. If I remember well, I could see some time ago a solution, or a discussion about what is to be done (in C#, even if not sure about that)...

Comment: Whilst it should be possible to send *any* file encoded BASE64 unmolested some net nanny software can't resist removing certain four letter AngloSaxon words from text streams. ISTR the risk at least one four letter obscenity increases markedly for files longer than about 1MB. Empirically I have actually seen far more PDF files get corrupted in transmission this way than anything else.  XLSX/XLSM is considered dangerous in most corporate environments and will get automatically stripped from emails. Check the two errant files against each other to see what gives.

Comment: Please, look ăhereî(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211829/encoding-and-decoding-excel-file-as-base64-string), even it is about C#, especially the encoding part. Forget about the second step of string transforming. It is not mentioning anything about the file size...

Comment: @FunThomas Yes the file is an xlsx file that I have added to the API to be output. What I have noticed however is that the base64 string is fine as I'm able to use an online converter on the base64 string just fine. When the decoder runs the base64 string and outputs a byte array.. that's where the issue seems to be. Is the above code for the decode function not able to produce a correct byte array? Or is the byte array correct but writing it to file is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe it was so simple stupid.. if the byte array is not explicitly declared as a byte() array and instead is a variant/byte it won't work when writing it to file if the byte array came from a decoded base64 string of an xlsx file.

It will work fine for pdf, but not for xlsx where it has to be explicitly declared. This is the answer, but can anyone shed some light as to why?

TLDR a painful lesson on why Option Explicit is required.